# perform something similar to offset in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have this mapping table.

```
df <- data.frame(L = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                 fli.1 = c(0, 700, 1500, 2000, 3500, 5600, 11000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.2 = c(0, 200, 1000, 2900, 3000, 5500, 10000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.3 = c(0, 600, 1200, 2500, 3900, 5000, 10000, 22000, 58000),
                 fli.4 = c(0, 300, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 14000, 20000, 50000),
                 fli.5 = c(0, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000))
```

I have another dataframe which is

```
d <- data.frame(
  quantity = c(300, 368, 568, 20, 1000, 37659, 45000, 2500, 4500, 78453, 1200, 1589), 
  fli = c("fli.1", "fli.1", "fli.4", "fli.5", "fli.2", "fli.2", "fli.5", "fli.1", "fli.2", "fli.2", "fli.3", "fli.4")
)
```

i need to create another vector in dataframe d such that it is taking values from dataframe df. vertically look for less than quantity and horizontally match fli. and give the index.

for e.g. for 37659 it would be 20000 which is 8th row and from column fli.1, so display 8.

This is just an demonstration.

I need to apply it for huge dataset. around 1 million.

i tried creating a matrix but it takes time. i need something faster.

I am trying to edit this code the code below to perform the above.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(d)
tmp <- melt(df[, !"L"], id.vars = NULL, measure.vars = patterns("^fli"))
d[, It := tmp[.SD, on = .(variable = fli, value <= quantity), mult = "last", j = x.value]]
rm(tmp)
```

Comment: when you say *"it would be 20000 ... so display 8"*, are you saying that the new column in `d` should have the value 8?

Comment: yes, an additional column on right in the data frame d and which should be like 1,1,2,1... and yes for 20000 it will be 8.

Comment: Fyi, when you're talking about 1mi+ rows/column or whatever, reshaping operations (`melt`) can be rather expensive, it might be best to avoid them :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why creating a matrix would be slower than using a dataframe. Where are you loading the data from? What about skipping the initial dataframe and using the matrix directly? (you could use fli=c(1,2,3,1,2) and use the indices directly to index the matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can do this:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
d[, newcol := findInterval(quantity, c(df[[fli]], Inf)), by = .(fli)]
#     quantity    fli newcol
#        <num> <char>  <int>
#  1:      300  fli.1      1
#  2:      368  fli.1      1
#  3:      568  fli.4      2
#  4:       20  fli.5      1
#  5:     1000  fli.2      3
#  6:    37659  fli.2      8
#  7:    45000  fli.5      8
#  8:     2500  fli.1      4
#  9:     4500  fli.2      5
# 10:    78453  fli.2      9
# 11:     1200  fli.3      3
# 12:     1589  fli.4      3
```

Because this does this by `fli`, the call to `findInterval` is done once per unique `fli`, so at most (?) `ncol(df)-1` times; since we're doing all of that group at a time, we're capitalizing on the vectorized operation of `findInterval`.

We use `c(., Inf)` in order to be able to capture values outside of the max of a `df` column.

If `df$L` is not a perfect sequence, then we can index it with:

```r
df[, L := .I * 2L] # for demonstration
#        L fli.1 fli.2 fli.3 fli.4 fli.5
#    <int> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     2     0     0     0     0     0
# 2:     4   700   200   600   300   500
# 3:     6  1500  1000  1200  1000  1000
# 4:     8  2000  2900  2500  2000  2000
# 5:    10  3500  3000  3900  3000  3500
# 6:    12  5600  5500  5000  5000  5000
# 7:    14 11000 10000 10000 14000 10000
# 8:    16 20000 20000 22000 20000 20000
# 9:    18 50000 50000 58000 50000 50000
d[, newcol := findInterval(quantity, c(df[[fli]], Inf)), by = .(fli)][, L := df$L[newcol]]
#     quantity    fli newcol     L
#        <num> <char>  <int> <int>
#  1:      300  fli.1      1     2
#  2:      368  fli.1      1     2
#  3:      568  fli.4      2     4
#  4:       20  fli.5      1     2
#  5:     1000  fli.2      3     6
#  6:    37659  fli.2      8    16
#  7:    45000  fli.5      8    16
#  8:     2500  fli.1      4     8
#  9:     4500  fli.2      5    10
# 10:    78453  fli.2      9    18
# 11:     1200  fli.3      3     6
# 12:     1589  fli.4      3     6
```

This can of course be done in one-step with

```r
d[, newcol := df$L[findInterval(quantity, c(df[[fli]], Inf))], by = .(fli)]
```

**Note**: per [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html): its second argument (`vec`) must be *"sorted (weakly) increasing"*.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. this is what i was looking for. it is very fast as compared to my existing code which uses matrix.